# Select single xml node w/ namespaces with XPath Csharp

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces

Why does my xmlNode nodes always end up null? I put in the namespaces it asked for.
Below is the xml I have loaded.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
       <soapenv:Body>
              <queryResponse>
                     <result>
                            <done>true</done>
                            <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"></queryLocator>
                            <records xsi:type="sf:Opportunity">
                                   <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"></sf:Id>
                                   <sf:Account xsi:type="sf:Account">
                                          <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"></sf:Id>
                                          <sf:Account_ID__c>AccountIdXXXX</sf:Account_ID__c>
                                          <sf:Name>The Account Name</sf:Name>
                                      </sf:Account>
                                   <sf:OpportunityLineItems>
                                          <done>true</done>
                                          <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"></queryLocator>
                                          <records xsi:type="sf:OpportunityLineItem">
                                                 <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"></sf:Id>
                                                 <sf:Brand_Desc__c>Another Description</sf:Brand_Desc__c>
                                                 <sf:PricebookEntry xsi:type="sf:PricebookEntry">
                                                        <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"></sf:Id>
                                                        <sf:Product2 xsi:type="sf:Product2">
                                                               <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"></sf:Id>
                                                               <sf:Description>The Product Description</sf:Description>
                                                           </sf:Product2>
                                                    </sf:PricebookEntry>
                                                 <sf:Product_Group_for_Storage_Sys__c>Some Descriptive Text</sf:Product_Group_for_Storage_Sys__c>
                                                 <sf:Product_Type_Formula__c>Enterprise</sf:Product_Type_Formula__c>
                                                 <sf:Product_Type_Text__c>Enterprise</sf:Product_Type_Text__c>
                                                 <sf:Product_Type__c>Enterprise</sf:Product_Type__c>
                                                 <sf:Product_code_for_analytics__c>Code Here</sf:Product_code_for_analytics__c>
                                             </records>
                                          <size>1</size>
                                      </sf:OpportunityLineItems>
                                   <sf:PartnerAccount xsi:type="sf:Account">
                                          <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"></sf:Id>
                                          <sf:Account_ID__c>IDXXXX</sf:Account_ID__c>
                                      </sf:PartnerAccount>
                                   <sf:Partner_Account_Name__c>The Partner Name</sf:Partner_Account_Name__c>
                               </records>
                            <size>1</size>
                        </result>
                 </queryResponse>
          </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image]

```
xmlSoapRequest.LoadXml(strResultString);
            XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlSoapRequest.NameTable);
            man.AddNamespace("sf", "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com");
            man.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");



            XmlNode nodes = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/queryResponse/result/records/sf:Account/sf:Name", man);
```

It seems like I am doing everything correctly. I gave it the darn namespaces. But nodes always ends up null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler XPath statement ended up working.

```
XmlNode nodes = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//sf:Account/sf:Name", man);
```